# Is there a Japanese term or slang for "[something specific] piqued my interest after watching an anime"?

Tags: slang, anime, terminology

I remember long ago that there was a term for "some hints or actions that spark your curiosity when watching anime", but I can't remember it. Do you know it?

For example, I have watched some anime that uses a word, references a real event, or a real process for doing something, and then I look up on the Internet about that matter and I learn something new.

[This question here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5326/what-are-yasaburo-and-professor-eating-in-episode-9) is a clear example of something that got your attention and it make you search for it.

I guess it also extends to looking up songs/groups (learning about them) because you liked them in the anime in the first place.

Comment: Are you talking about きっかけ? It's something that gets you started on something (impetus).

Comment: Reposted from Anime.SE: https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/66636/2516 (because currently it's unclear if the question is about anime at all)

Comment: Probably, but just take into account that maybe has something to do in particular with translators that also add footnotes to point something you have missed out as you will normally dont know those details...

In the other exchange, they refer to "ki ni narimasu" as option